# Cannot get groups folder on iOS 11 simulators

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11

The following always returns nil on all iPhone 11 simulators but works fine on devices and simulators prior to 11.

```
let containerURL = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.my.group.name.here")
```

Anyone else encounter this? What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a whole day of debugging, I think I might have found a workaround.

I think it has to do with the Bundle Identifier. So if you have a bundle identifier `xx`, it fails, but it works if your bundle identifier is `xx.xx`

So for example it fails with Bundle Identifier: `musicapp`

It will work with the Bundle Identifier: `com.steventso.musicapp` or even `com.musicapp`

Since you can't change the Bundle Identifier after you've released the app to the public, the workaround is to create a new Target that you use strictly for development and when using the simulator where it is under a bundle identifier with the naming scheme `xx.xx`

Yeah it's a strange bug I hope they fix, but I think I was wrong in even naming it with the scheme of `xx` in the first place.

It's hard to tell if this will break iPhone X since there is no physical device to test on, so fingers cross this works out okay.

Comment: I think you're right. Our bundle id doesn't have periods in it either

Comment: I cannot believe this is still broken - come on guys